# 429 activex component can't create object - importing data from .xlsm file

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro to import some data from excel sheets. On some computers it works but on some it occurs an error `Runtime Error 429 - ActiveX Component Can't Create Object` while I want to import from .xlsm file - other format files works fine. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You may want to Check if this Update is on some of the computers but not others

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025036

If your installed Updates it would be "Update for Microsoft Office 2007 suites (KB2920794)"

Reversing this Windows Update Fixed this issue on some computers.

This is a Shot in the dark as this is a very Vague error, But who knows.